# Accept argument in node_module require

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I am creating a node module and I am hoping to force the user to pass an argument during module require.

Like this:

```
const sample = require('sample-module')('username')
```

Inside my sample-module, I have declared the public functions like this (these are imports from other files):

```
module.exports = {
  addNewFolder: folderHandler.addNewFolder,
  printToFile: printHandler.printToFile,
  deleteFolder: folderHandler.deleteFolder
  // more functions
}

// Here I want to add a function that will accept the argument passed.
function setUserName(name) {
  // some handling here, in this case, 'name' is 'username' as we passed in during require
}
```

How can I do this?

Lastly, I prefer to require using like this:

```
const sample = require('sample-module')('username')
```

Rather than:

```
const sample = require('sample-module')
sample.setUserName('username')
```

Help anyone? Thanks!

Comment: if the default export is a function it will accept parameters normally, just do `module.exports = function(username){}`

Comment: Don't export an object literal if you want to export a function. Also, you shouldn't force the user to call the function and pass an argument if your methods that "*are imports from other files*" don't depend on the argument value.

Comment: @Bergi - this username is quite important as it will be used by the 'imports from other files'.. I was thinking like a constructor, but I do not want to complicate things by forcing myself to use a class.

Comment: @keechan How will they access it? It might become clearer if you could show how they need to use the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `module.exports` to function like this

```js
const test = (arg) => {
  console.log(arg);
};

module.exports = function (requireArg) {
  return {
    test: test(requireArg),
  };
};
```

then require it

```js
const { test } = require('./test')('apple');
```